# ver si ya existe relacion OnetoOne en Django

Tags: django, django-models

tengo una app en la que hago un CRUD de prestamo de libros, un libro solo puede ser prestado una vez(tiene una relacion onetoone con la tabla clientes), como podria hacer para chequear si el libro ya existe en la "loansTable" para que envie un mensaje al intentar agregarlo nuevamente (aca paso las tres tablas juntas pero estan cada una en una app diferente)

models.py

```
class loansTable(models.Model):
bookLoan = models.OneToOneField(booksTable,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
clientLoan = models.ForeignKey(clientsTable,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
dateLoan = models.DateField()
dateReturn = models.DateField()
status = models.CharField(max_length=10,default='borrowed')
def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.bookLoan,self.clientLoan,self.status)


class booksTable(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.name)


class clientsTable(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

Views.py

```
def loans_list(request):
qs = loansTable.objects.all()
paginator = Paginator(qs,5)
page_number = request.GET.get('page',1)

try:
    page_obj = paginator.page(page_number)
except (PageNotAnInteger, EmptyPage):
    raise Http404(f'Invalid page {page_number}. That page contains no results')

context = {'list':qs, 'object_list': page_obj,'page_obj': page_obj}
return render(request, 'loansApp/loans.html',context)


def loan_add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form= LoansForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
       return redirect('/loansApp/loans')
  else:
    form= LoansForm()
 return render (request,'loansApp/addloan.html',{'form':form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asumo que le pasas el id del book cuando lo añades al loan entonces ahi solamente es que verifiques que está en la tabla de loan asi:

```
try:
   prestamo= loansTable.objects.get(bookLoan_id=id_del_book_que_llega_por_parametro)
   return mensaje de si esta
except loansTable.DoesNotExist:
   return mensaje de no esta y añadir el libro al loanstable
```

Como consejo nombra los modelos en singular, con mayuscula inicial y sin el table asi: BookLoan, Book  etc...

Comment: Hola raiganfast, como seria pasar el id del book?? lo que he intentado hacer no me ha funcionado, muchas gracias

Comment: Bueno natogua como me lo imagino yo tu tienes un listado de libros digamos que los tienes en una tabla (como ejemplo) entonces cada linea de la tabla corresponde a un registro de un libro por lo tanto digamos que hay un botoncito que diga prestar a ese prestar debería de llegarle el id del libro que quieres prestar entonces seria def presar_libro(request, id_book): etc... ahí haces el préstamo y haces la verificación, en todo caso depende de la lógica que tu estés o  vayas aplicar. Recuerda que los  ids los puedes pasar por url. Me cuentas!